# Using a loop variable in a let in a shared example call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing specs for a PDF generated with RoR & Prawn. There are a bunch of filter options (24 of them) for that PDF. In order to not miss any important specs I'm generating the filter options in a `before :context` block and saving them in an instance variable.

Where my problem starts is when trying to iterate over all of the filter options and run shared examples, to test for basics that don't change much with different filters.

This is what my code looks like for all these filters and the documentations filter (the `filter_setting` method is just a helper to access specific `@major_filter_options`):

```
describe 'pdf' do
  before :context do
    @major_filter_options = {}
    @major_filter_options.define_them
  end

  describe 'basic content' do
    before :context do
      @filter_options_with_docu = {}
      # find all the filters that have the docu option enabled
      @major_filter_options.each do |key, mfo|
        @filter_options_with_docu[key] = mfo if key.to_s.include? 'docu'
      end
    end

    24.times do |t| # can't access major_filter_options.size here.. it's nil.
      include_examples 'first_3_pages' do
        let(:pdf) do
          filter_options = filter_setting(@major_filter_options.keys[t])
          ProjectReport::ReportGenerator.new.generate(project, filter_options, user).render
        end
        let(:page_analysis) { PDF::Inspector::Page.analyze(pdf) }
      end
    end

    12.times do |t| # @print_options_with_docu is also nil at this point
      include_examples 'documentation_content' do
        let(:pdf) do
          filter_options = filter_setting(@filter_options_with_docu.keys[t])
          ProjectReport::ReportGenerator.new.generate(project, filter_options, user).render
        end
        let(:page_analysis) { PDF::Inspector::Page.analyze(pdf) }
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
```

I have 2 big problems:

One is that this `24.times`, `12.times` and so on (there's a bunch of them) are bothering me because it makes maintainance a lot harder. A new filter option would change all the values, and finding all of the values to change them is very susceptible to mistakes in my opinion.

The other problem is the fact that the variable iterated here like this:
`12.times do |t|` doesn't actually seem to iterate when I'm inside of any of these `let`'s:

```
let(:pdf) do
  filter_options = filter_setting(@major_filter_options.keys[t])
  puts t
  # ...
end
```

The `puts t` here will print 11 every time (the filter is also the same every time).
After some reading I found [a gist example](https://gist.github.com/nruth/501296). The problem looked similar enough, but sadly puting a `describe` block around it didn't do much.

```
24.times do |t|
  describe
    # same as before
  end
end
```

Interestingly enough though, when doing `puts t` again in that setup, it would be 6 every time, which left me a little more confused.

I should also mention, that the reason for splitting them up like this is that I have shared examples that only apply for certain filters. If someone has a better idea on how to, for example iterate over the `@major_filter_options` and then just call certain shared examples depending on the current hash `key`, I'm all ears!

Comment: I can't say for sure but `include_examples` works only once per context. I think you have to surround it with a uniq context like  `context "...#{t}" do`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding your inability to call `.times` on the instance variables you defined in `before :context` blocks:**

RSpec works in two phases. In the first phase it executes the Ruby code in the spec file; the `let` and `before` and `it` methods store their blocks to be run later. In the second phase it actually runs the tests, i.e. the contents of `let` and `before` and `it` blocks. The `before :context` blocks don't define thost instance variables until the second phase, so the `.times` statements, which run in the first phase, can't see the instance variables.

The solution is to put the filter options someplace that's initialized before RSpec gets to the `.times` statements, like a constant.

**Regarding `include_examples` in a loop always using the same value of the loop variable:**

`include_examples` includes the given shared examples in the current context. If you include the same examples more than once, the examples themselves will be included multiple times, but `let`s in the last inclusion will overwrite `lets` in all of the previous inclusions. [The RSpec documentation has a clear example.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)

The solution is to use `it_behaves_like` instead of `include_examples`. `it_behaves_like` puts the included examples in a nested example group, so the `let`s can't overwrite one another.

Applying those two solutions gives something like the following:

```
describe 'pdf' do
  describe 'basic content' do
    MAJOR_FILTER_OPTIONS = # code that initializes them
    MAJOR_FILTER_OPTIONS.values.each do |filter_option|
      it_behaves_like 'first_3_pages' do
        let(:pdf) do
          filter_options = filter_setting(filter_option)
          ProjectReport::ReportGenerator.new.generate(project, filter_options, user).render
        end
        let(:page_analysis) { PDF::Inspector::Page.analyze(pdf) }
      end
    end

    FILTER_OPTIONS_WITH_DOCU = # code that chooses them from MAJOR_FILTER_OPTIONS
    FILTER_OPTIONS_WITH_DOCU.values.each do |filter_option|
      it_behaves_like 'documentation_content' do
        let(:pdf) do
          filter_options = filter_setting(filter_option)
          ProjectReport::ReportGenerator.new.generate(project, filter_options, user).render
        end
        let(:page_analysis) { PDF::Inspector::Page.analyze(pdf) }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: could you think of any reason why these loops would work individually (if I comment out the other) but not in combination? By work I mean the tests pass. But running everything results in some failing tests and tweaking the Hashes to leave out a few filter options would result in different tests failing.
I brought the minimal required examples (to reproduce the failures) down to 50% (still ~350) and am running rspec --bisect on them, but that seems like it's going to take very long, after more than an hour I saw this `- Remaining non-failing examples (337):`

Comment: I don't see in the question, and I didn't suggest in my answer, anything that should have side effects that might break later tests. Unless you can think of something in these tests that changes global state, `rspec --bisect` and debugging the result seems like the way to go.

Comment: Found the problem, thought I'd let you know that it had nothing to do with what was discussed here, your suggestion works beautifully!